# No boot option for Windows after Boot Repair

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I have recently installed Ubuntu 14.02. I intended to have Ubuntu, next to the also recently upgraded Windows 10 (dual-boot). Installation went okay, but after reboot I had no option to boot into Ubuntu. I have used the Boot-Repair instructions found here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair  (the second option; I installed it through Ubuntu temporary version on my bootable USB)

The result is here:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/12849745/

Now I have no option to boot Windows and I have no idea what to do anymore.

Thank you

Comment: Run `sudo update-grub` in a terminal and check again.

Comment: So that did it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `sudo update-grub` in a terminal will make GRUB scan for installed OSes and add Windows to the list.